# Preload images for HTML5 app on mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, safari

Is it possible to pre-load a set of images for an HTML5 app (targeting mobile Safari)?

In the ideal scenario, the app's startup image persists until certain images are loaded.

We tried using the CSS background attribute and including each image as a separate background, but that fails to pre-load the images and persist the startup image.

Here's our HTML for setting the startup image, but this fails to persist until all the images are loaded:

```
<!-- iPhone 3 and 4 Non-Retina -->
<link rel='apple-touch-startup-image' media='(device-width: 320px)' href='/images/x/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to preload images using jquery.

```
<style type="text/css">
.start_up{width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;z-index:999;display:none;}
.start_up img{width:100%;height:100%;display:block;}
</style>

<div class="start_up"> <img src="startup-image.png" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //showing startup image. By default it will be display:none via css.
    $('.start_up').show();

    //load img
    var imgArray = ['image 1 path','image 2 path', 'image 3 path'];
    var total = imgArray.length;
    var imgLoaded = 0;
    for (var i in imgArray) {
        $("<img />").load(function() {
            imgLoaded++;
            if (imgLoaded == total) {
                //when all images loaded we hide start up image.
                $('.start_up').hide();
            }
        }).error(function() {
            imgLoaded++;
            if (imgLoaded == total) {
                //when all images loaded even error in img loading, we hide startup image.
                $('.start_up').hide();
            }   
        }).attr("src", imgArray[i]);
    }   
});

</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but how do we persist the HTML5 startup image until all the images are preloaded?

Answer (score 0):

You should display the "Startup Image" using HTML, and add the other images using javascript in the `$(document).ready` event.

//edit

rajni's answer has a good example of what should be done. However, you should read the warning [on this page](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) regarding the `.load()` event.

Comment: thanks, we display the startup image using HTML now (updated question with code) but the startup image hides before all the images needed for the app are loaded. how can we persist the image until all images are preloaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Image` constructor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) to preload images even when the DOM is not yet ready:

```
var srcArray = ['/path/to/image1.jpg', '/path/to/image2.jpg']; // your image sources

function loadImages(srcArray, callback) {
  var loaded   = []; // here the loaded images will be contained

  for (var i; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
    // wrap the loop into a closure because onload is asynchronous
    (function(src) {
      // construct a new image
      var img = new Image();

      // use the onload event of the image
      // you can react to errors or load aborts using 'onerror' or 'onabort'
      img.onload = function() {
        loaded.push(img);

        // call the callback once all images are loaded
        loaded.length === srcArray.length && callback.call(this, loaded); 
      };

      // set the source
      img.src = src;
    })(srcArray[i]);
  }
}

// an easy, convenient function to load some images and do something
// when they are loaded
loadImages(srcArray, function(images) {
  // when this function is called, all images are loaded
  // use them as you please
});
```

Comment: thanks, but how do we persist the HTML5 startup image until all the images are preloaded?

Comment: Use a normal html image and then replace the image with `loadImages`.